# Перезагрузка ADSL модема скриптом VBScript через telnet

Tags: windows, vbscript, telnet

Нужна программа или скрипт для перезагрузки `ADSL` модема.
Порылся в интернете, нашел интересный скрипт (написанный на `VBScript`).

```
On Error Resume Next

strComputer = "."
strTarget = "turbo.uralcom.com" 'IP address or hostname
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")
Set colPings = objWMIService.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_PingStatus where Address = '" & strTarget & "'")
If Err = 0 Then
    Err.Clear
    For Each objPing in colPings 'избавиться от форича
        If Err = 0 Then
            Err.Clear
            If objPing.StatusCode = 0 Then
                ' если статус = 0, пустая строка - другое
            Else
                Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
                oShell.Run "telnet.exe 192.168.1.1"
                WScript.Sleep 1000
                oShell.SendKeys "user" & chr(13)
                WScript.Sleep 1000
                oShell.SendKeys "password" & chr(13)
                WScript.Sleep 1000
                oShell.SendKeys "reboot" & chr(13)
            End If
        Else
            Err.Clear
            WScript.Echo "Unable to call Win32_PingStatus on " & strComputer & "."
        End If
    Next
Else
    Err.Clear
    WScript.Echo "Unable to call Win32_PingStatus on " & strComputer & "."
End If
```

При выполнение этого скрипта есть небольшой косяк. В общем это связано с вводом текстовых значений: логина, пароля и команды. В место них вводятся оброкозябрыб, и вход не происходит. Я заменил логи и пароль на числовые значение все нормально вводится и входит, а вот команду ввести не получается. В чем может быть проблема с этими аброкозябрами. Провера на ОС Windows XP и 7.

Вот что получается в Telnet

```
                ===========================
                  Welcome to ZXDSL  M-101 A
                ===========================

ZTE Inc., Software Release ZXDSL 831CIIV5.2.0a_E09_BY1

Login name: 14-9,
Password:
Login incorrect. Try again.
Login name: 5~52//
Password:
```

Answer (score 1):

Тоже парился с этим полдня, решилось изменением языка системы по умолчанию на английский...